# which framework to integrate into my project to work with web-services

Tags: web-services, ios

i'm working on JSON web-services and i want to know which one of these frameworks are obligatory for my iOS application to interact with web-services :

**JSON framework**

**ASIHTTPRequest**

**MBProgressHUD**

are they all necessar for my IOS app ? thx in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're just reading data from a web-service the JSON framework is enough. Writing a class that downloads a JSON file from an URL does not take much time and isn't difficult. For this task an extra framework would be over the top.

Take a look at the Apple docs (NSURLRequest, NSURLConnection). It's really simple.